# How to scrape a content from links stored in a list using beautiful soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to scrape title of all the post present in a main website. `main` is a list which contains 6 or 7 url in it:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import Beautifulsoup 

r=requests.get("https://forums.oneplus.com/")
s=BeautifulSoup(r.content)
links=s.find_all("a",{"class" : "focus-content"})
url2=[] 
for link in links:
    url2.append(link.get("href"))

url1="https://forums.oneplus.com/"
for u in url2:
    main=url1+u
    print(main)

for m in main:
    r1=requests.get(m)
    s1=BeautifulSoup(r1)
    title=s1.find("span", {"class" : "title"})
    print(title)
```

Comment: You can't pass a requests object to beautiful soup.  You should do: `r1=requests.get(m).text`. BS4 might also give you a warning so: `BeautifulSoup(r1, 'html.parser')`.  Then printing title won't give you exactly what you want and `title.text` will (as title is a soup element object, not a string).  You aren't returning the title properly, I'd recommend appending them to a list.

Comment: You don't tell us what the problem is with your code. Does it give an error? Does it not do anything at all?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your variable `main` as a list. In your code you update the variable `main` in each iteration of the loop. At the end, the `main` will be string containing the last url from `url2` list. If you then supply `main` to next loop, it will iterate over individual characters.

After few cosmetic changes this should get your titles:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r=requests.get("https://forums.oneplus.com/")
s=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
links=s.find_all("a",{"class" : "focus-content"})
url2=[]
for link in links:
    url2.append(link.get("href"))

url1 = "https://forums.oneplus.com/"
main = []
for u in url2:
    main.append(url1 + u)

for m in main:
    r1 = requests.get(m)
    s1 = BeautifulSoup(r1.text, 'lxml')
    title=s1.find("span", {"class" : "title"})
    print(title.text.strip())
```

Prints:

```
Weekly 240: We release the updates and get reading
Shot on OnePlus: Part 6 – Best Slo-mo Video / Animal Photos
Android P Beta Developer Preview 3 for OnePlus 6
[Let's Talk] To whom are you gonna give your appreciation in this Community?
[Let's Talk] What Does Your OnePlus Device Replace?
[Let's Talk]  Loyalty to tech companies
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, Thank you for your response but after trying your code I am still getting same error.this below code is used to get value of main list import requests
from bs4 import Beautifulsoup
r=requests.get("https://forums.oneplus.com/")
s=BeautifulSoup(r.content)
links=s.find_all("a",{"class" : "focus-content"})
   url2=[]
for link in links :
    url2.append(link.get("href"))
url1="https://forums.oneplus.com/"
for u in url2:
    main=url1+u    please let me know where I am making mistake

Comment: @sonu Can you edit your question and post the error there? It's hard to see otherwise what is wrong...

Comment: Hi Andrej I am not able to edit my question to attach the error   the last line error is MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'h': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://h?  and this is the first line MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'h': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://h?

Comment: dont know when ever I try to edit it it shows indentation wrong or add some more comments which I did

Comment: hi andrej I have placed my code and the error in this link    https://anotepad.com/notes/hn7k2k

Comment: @Sonu I updated your question and also my answer. Now it should work!

Comment: Thank you so so so much for your help..it's working..can you please highlight me what mistake did I committed in this code ...